# Annuity, progression

Tags: statistics

Questions are:
2.  A sinking fund is created for the redemption of debartures of Rs 100000 at the end of 25 years. How much money should be provided out of profits each semiannually for the sinking fund, if the investment can earn interest 4% compounded semiannually.

3. A person borrows RM20,000 on condition to repay it with compound interest at 5.2% compounded quaterly, by quarterly installment of RM400 each. In how many years will the debt be paid off?
4. An apartment is purchased on istallment basis, such that RM 320,000 as cash price and installment of RM3000 each payable at the end of the month. If the interest rate is charged 3.7% compounded monthly, how many years will the installment end?
5. Find the sum of the first 30 terms of the arithmetic progression whose fourth and eleventh term are 30 and 107, respectively.
6. Find the sum of the first ten terms of the geometric progression 1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8,..

I answered all of them:[image: Here's question 2 and 3] [image: These are questions 4, 5 and 6]

but my lecturer sent them back. Now I don't really now where's my mistake (may be wrong calculation). I really get stack in here.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to number 2 provides the future value of Rs 100,000 deposited semiannually after 25 years at 4% compounded semiannually. You needed to calculate a semi annual deposit amount so that after 25 years you would have Rs 100,000.
$$
\begin{align*}
100000 &=d\frac{\left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)^{50}-1}{\frac{0.04}{2}}\\
100000\frac{\frac{0.04}{2}}{\left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)^{50}-1} &=d\\
1182.32&=d
\end{align*}
$$